# Jquery 1.9.1 Slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a slide animation with Jquery 1.9.1 that I will not need to add any additional script libraries?
My web project is becoming a nightmare as jquery 1.7 (with the slide animation and other js libraries) are causing a lot of conflicts. 
My resolve is to find few lines of codes that does that with jquery 1.9.1. Any suggestion please?

Comment: There are slide animations already as of jquery 1.7. Which ones are you looking for, be more specific

Comment: I want it in 1.9.1. Just something to auto slide. I am doing that on several image files.

Comment: Like I mentioned be more specific to the issue at hand, post some code

Answer (score 0):

Please check [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown) [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp) and [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle) in jQuery API documentation.

Comment: This would have been fine but I need it to auto slide as users can add  picture files to the effect

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario? I also didn't get what you mean by 'auto slide'. Or any fiddle of something that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

would you consider using [jQuery .animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

it is as simple as:

```
$("#myObject").animate({
height:+=100
},300,"easeIn",function(){
//do stuff once animation is complete
});
```

where 300 is the duration of the animation in milliseconds,
"easeIn" is the easing type, more [here](http://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html)
and the 2nd function is what to do once the animation is complete.

EDIT:

in ***some cases*** you might be required to set the position of the object to absolute first for the animation to work correctly

```
.css({"position":"absolute"});
```

Comment: I think you all have given me the clues I require through your queries on what I actually want to achieve. Thanks.